# How to digitize a vector field?

Tags: image-processing, vector, map, digitization

Is there some way that I can digitize both the direction and the magnitude of a vector field accessible in JPEG format?

To clarify what I mean, I want to have the numerical value of: 1)magnitude and 2) direction of all the vectors in a meteorological map like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract numeric data representing those arrows from the picture?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, exactly

Comment: interesting...it's probably possible to build a neural net that does it with some accuracy, but it might be quicker to build a sort of GUI tool that lets you move around the image and manually "trace" the arrows' endpoints with a mouse...